# Fragment exit animations do not run

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation, android-transitions

I cannot seem to get the exit animations to run when the back button is pressed. Fragments are added using the below code:

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left, R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
ft.replace(android.R.id.content, fragment);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

I'm using the support library (obviously) and actionbarsherlock. When I want to show the next fragment, the current fragment calls up to the above code which is in the containing activity.

The transitions in play just fine, but when the back button is pressed, the current fragment disappears and then the in transition runs. the out transition is totally skipped.

Answer (score 3):

For me, the issue was having the **container** layout to which I added the fragment with `android:height="wrap_content"` this caused the height to become `0` as soon as the slide down animation **starts** making the animation invisible.

Try setting your container view an actual height, or make it `"match_parent"` with `android:gravity` to control the position of the fragment within it.